# Historical US population by Age/Sex

Tags: data-request, us-census, historical

I'm looking for US population data since 1900 (or earlier) with age and sex breakdowns. The data appears to be available from the US Census Bureau, but in may different text or Excel files, sometimes differently per decade. For example, [1980s data](https://www.census.gov/popest/data/historical/1980s/index.html) is one loosely structured text file.

I thought this might be common enough that someone knows of an aggregated source, or multiple files with consistent structure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could see if [Historical Statistics of the United States 1789-1945](http://www2.census.gov/prod2/statcomp/documents/HistoricalStatisticsoftheUnitedStates1789-1945.pdf) is useful.

[image]

You could also calculate it using [iPUMS](https://usa.ipums.org/usa/).

Comment: specifically https://usa.ipums.org/usa/sampdesc.shtml

Comment: Surprisingly Chrome's PDF viewer can paste text out of that PDF! iPUMS is working but only has 10-year data before 2000.

Comment: Well, for the statistics the questioner is interested in (1900 and earlier), iPUMS is drawing from the only source that would have this information for the US. Anthony Damico's comment provides a useful link that explains these data sources.